# Delete none AGTC charachter in a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Text file and it should contains A,G,C,T characters. However it sometimes has some unknown characters (very few) which I want to delete and if it is N replace it with A. Also I want to escape the lines which starts with a `>` symbol.

So far I know only how to replace N with A, which I do like this :

```
 sed "s/N/A/g" file1.fa >file2.fasta
```

But I don't know how to do the first task.

Example :

Initial file

> first line
>   AGCCCMCCCN

Target file should be like this

> first line
>   AGCCCCCCA

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: edit your post so that the input format is clear. Use the code block instead of the quote one

Answer (score 2):

You can do another substitution on your `sed`

```
sed -e 's/N/A/g' -e 's/[^AGCT>]//g' -e 's/^>/\\>/' -e 's/[^\]>//g' file1.fa > file2.fasta
```

**Pattern 1**

```
-e 's/N/A/g'
```

Your pattern, replaces all instances of N with A first of all.

**Pattern 2**

```
-e 's/[^AGCT>]//g'
```

Secondly replace all characters that aren't A, G, C, T or > with nothing.

**Pattern 3**

```
-e 's/^>/\\>/'
```

Then replace all instances of > that are at the start of a string with \>

**Pattern 4**

```
-e 's/[^\]>//g'
```

Finally remove all > characters that aren't preceded by a \